# sizeof Cannot take the size of a variable of a managed type

Tags: c#, api, hardware

I am attempting to use some example code for some hardware, a [MicroGate controller card](http://www.microgate.com).  They provide some example code, and I am running into an error with the line that uses sizeof.  Here is the example code:

```
public static uint GetPortID(string name)
    {
        uint i, rc, count;
        uint port_id = 0;
        MGSL_PORT[] ports;

        /* get count of available ports */
        rc = MgslEnumeratePorts(null, 0, out count);
        if (rc != 0 || count == 0)
            return 0;

        /* allocate memory to hold port information */
        ports = new MGSL_PORT[count];

        /* get port information */
        rc = MgslEnumeratePorts(ports, (uint)(count * sizeof(MGSL_PORT)), out count);
        if (rc != 0 || count == 0)
            return 0;

        /* search for entry with matching name */
        for (i=0; i < count; i++) {
            string port_name;
            char[] port_chars = new char[25];
            uint j;
            fixed (byte* sendBuf = ports[i].DeviceName)
            {
                for (j=0 ; j < 25; j++)
                    port_chars[j] = (char)sendBuf[j];
            }
            port_name = new string(port_chars);
            if (String.Compare(port_name.ToUpper(), name.ToUpper()) == 0) {
                port_id = ports[i].PortID;
                break;
            }
        }
        return port_id;
    }
```

On the line that is:

```
rc = MgslEnumeratePorts(ports, (uint)(count * sizeof(MGSL_PORT)), out count);
```

Visual Studio indicates "Cannot take the size of a variable of a managed type 'MGSL_PORT'.  Just out of curiosity, do we think this code may have worked in the past?  Do I need a different version of Visual Studio?  Any suggestions on how to fix it?  I can't imagine they would have provided this code example and not expected it to work.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `sizeof` ([reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf.aspx)) can only take certain types.  Is MGSL_PORT always the same size?  Is it a type that you can edit?

Comment: it is a struct defined in the API MicroGate provides.

Comment: Managed classes and non-bittable structs don't have a valid size.  You are pinvoking an unmanaged function, you must therefore provide the unmanaged size.  Use Marshal.SizeOf().  Btw, that is not a detail you can just omit from a question like this.

Comment: Sorry,  I am a little out of my element on this one.

Comment: You shouldn't edit an answer into your question. If you have an answer (and it's not one that someone else has posted), you should post it *as an answer*. Then (after a suitable delay), you should *accept* the answer that has worked out for you. That's how we know that your question has been successfully resolved.

Comment: Thanks... I was trying to clean up my question based on the comment by m.rogalski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the size of the struct by using Marshal.SizeOf.  My line of code is now:

```
rc = MgslEnumeratePorts(ports, (uint) (count * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SerialApi.MGSL_PORT))), out count);
```

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` ([reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf.aspx)) can only take certain types.  From the reference, it can take a `struct` only if it doesn't contain any reference types.  If the type does have a constant, known size ([API reference](http://www.synclink.com/html/hdlc3bol.htm)) you could do something like:

```
const int MGSL_SIZE = 37;
rc = MgslEnumeratePorts(ports, (uint)(count * MGSL_SIZE)), out count);
```

Comment: For non structs you can use `Marshall. SizeOf ()` method which will work on some types and you can create a `GCHandle` to pin the object in memory and then count it's size.

Comment: @m.rogalski your suggestion resulted in me trying:

    rc = MgslEnumeratePorts(ports, (uint) (count * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SerialApi.MGSL_PORT))), out count);

If you make your suggestion an answer I'll vote for it.

Comment: @BigDevJames If that's working for you then just edit your question with "Answer: <>" and that will be okay. If it's not working then I can investigate something :)